# Mysql - index does not improve query time

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `fund_historical_serie` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `patrimony` decimal(14,5) NOT NULL,
  `quota` decimal(14,5) NOT NULL,
  `fund_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKchhpobehjf7ebat11b4clv7yx` (`fund_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKchhpobehjf7ebat11b4clv7yx` FOREIGN KEY (`fund_id`) REFERENCES `fund` (`id`)
)
```

with about 8 mil records.

This query takes about 6sec to be executed:

```
select * from fund_historical_serie where fund_id IN (17957,308331) and `date` >= '2017-02-28' and  `date` <= '2017-08-30';
```

I'm creating an index on the date column but it's not improving the query time:

```
Alter table fund_historical_serie add index date_idx (`date`);
```

Query still takes 6 secs.

When I run the index query it shows 0 rows and 0 Records affected, Should not the index affect the current records on table ? or Do I have to re-insert then?

What else could I do to improve query time?

Thank you.

Comment: What's your query?, and Why is 6 seconds bad, especially in light of the fact that you are processing 8 million rows?

Comment: The index might even not been used.a EXPLAIN will tell you more.

Comment: This database is used by an application that runs this query but with hundreds of fund_id inside IN , with 300-500 fund_ids the query will take an hour.

Comment: Did you try it?  With hundreds of `fund_ids`, it will simply scan the entire table; that should not take hours.

Answer (score 0):

Composite Index on Fund_ID and Date will improve the performance.

Comment: I will try that